# UITableView in UIViewController not showing content

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

I have a UITableView in a UIViewController. Since other controls, such as a toolbar, needed to also be on this view, a table view controller was not an option.

In my view controller, I have implemented UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate. I have declared an outlet for my table view. In my main storyboard, I have set the table view's datasource and delegate to the view controller. (I've tried setting datasource and delegate programmatically as well)

My cellForRowAtIndexPath method confirms that the proper data is being loaded into the cells.

However, my table view is empty when the app runs.

View Controller header file:

```
    @interface FavoritesViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *allFavoriteObjects;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *faveTableView;

    -(void)loadData;

    @end
```

View Controller implementation file:

```
-(FavoriteCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    allCells = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    FavoriteCell *cell = (FavoriteCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[FavoriteCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellID];
    }
    Favorite *fave = [allFavoriteObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *currentHeightReading = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2fft", fave.currentFeetValue];
    NSString *currentCFSReading = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dcfs", fave.currentCFSValue];

    if([fave currentCFSValue] == 0){
        currentCFSReading = @"";
    }

    NSString *dateTimeLastUpdate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Last update: %@", [fave datelastUpdate]];

    [cell setGaugeID:[fave stationIdentifier]];
    [cell.lblMainTitle setText:[fave stationRealName]];
    [cell.lblGaugeLastUpdate setText:dateTimeLastUpdate];
    [cell.lblGaugeCFS setText:currentCFSReading];
    [cell.lblGaugeHeight setText:currentHeightReading];

    [allCells addObject:cell];

    return cell;
}
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    return [allFavoriteObjects count];
}
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1;
}
```

What could I be leaving out? Thanks!

Comment: Do you use static cells, by any chance ?:D

Comment: No, cells are dynamic

Comment: Just a comment `allCells` will always contain only the last cell. I do not know what you used it for but may be an issue. Else, for your initial problem, do you see the TableView (setting a backgroundColor) to be sure it is here could be an idea

Comment: -(FavoriteCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  this seems a bit odd, try replacing favoritecell with uitableviewcell

Comment: Where do you define cellID? Also, did you remember to change the class of the cell in the storyboard to FavoriteCell?

Comment: In addition to what @rdelmar mentioned, you should also check the `cell identifier` in Storyboard to make sure it matches the value of `cellID`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me was clicking and dragging the `dataSource` and `delegate` outlets directly to the yellow circle under the `ViewController` that the `UITableView` is located in. I was trying to set the tableView's delegate programmatically and it wasn't doing the job.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've entered cell identifier and class name for your cell in Storyboard.

When using Storyboard and prototype cells like this, *dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier* shouldn't ever return nil.
It will create new cell automatically if there isn't one in the queue.

Comment: Everything in cellForRowAtIndexPath is working properly. Cell identifier is set and matches the storyboard's value. Somewhere the data in my datasource is not being applied to the table view

Answer (score 0):

In your storyboard, set the UITableViewCell class to FavoriteCell. Remove references to allCells

Answer (score 0):

If you add UITableView inside the UIViewController, you need to set the frame size of the UITableView same as the frame size of the view inside the UIViewController, otherwise the tableview size may be 0, cannot display anything.

You can set the frame size of the UITableView if you create it in code by using:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGFloat width = self.view.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat height = self.view.frame.size.height - 50;
    CGRect tableFrame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);

    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:tableFrame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    // Set tableview delegate and datasource here
    [self.view addSubview:tableView];
}
```

Or set the frame size if you create the UITableView by storyboard in your case:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Set tableview delegate and datasource here
        faveTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
}
```